# Facebook Virtual Credit Cross-Platform Restrictions for Developer

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-credits

I noticed this on the Facebook Credits Terms page:

> You cannot have a cross-application virtual currency that can be purchased with Credits, so you may not accept Credits as payment for a virtual currency or other stored value item that can be used outside of the application where the payment was completed.

<sub>[source](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/credits/)</sub>

I want my game to work on Facebook, Kongregate, mobile platforms, and possibly my own website. I plan to use a universal virtual currency say XCash.
I was wondering if I can have players pay with Facebook Credits for XCash and this XCash can also be purchased through the other platforms such as on Kongregate with Kongregate credits, or through my website through a credit card system without violating the Facebook Credit Terms.

Comment: did you ever get an answer for this? I am interested too, note that it states 'the application' - if you are running the same app in a frame in FB and kongregate then it is still the same application.

Comment: Never got a clear answer. I've seen the game ereden use Feez before (now they changed it to FB credits and Kongregate credits). Both are the same app. I haven't tested whether players from Kongregate and interact with Facebook users in that game.

Comment: Answer I got from another site: "If I'm understanding the terms correctly, I would think you could do this if you keep your players separate. For any players that buy XCash in the Facebook version, they should only be able to spend that cash in the Facebook version. Basically maintain a separate database of players for each platform. Maybe if you wanted to maintain the same player account across platforms, you could get sophisticated and have separate in-game wallets, one for each platform (or a FB wallet and one for everyone else), but that might get messy from the user perspective."

Comment: thats what I thought. thanks.